# Amplify Storage put and S3 ManageUpload

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-amplify

Hi Stackoverflow folks,

I have lots of queries regarding differences between Amplify Storage and S3 SDK usage for uploading files to AWS.

I already have added the discussion here for reference - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/discussions/8973

I would be glad if you visit the link and understand my query and let me know your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For your question given the examples on github:

S3 SDK wraps around AWS API for S3 and uploads based on IAM policy (and bucket ACL).

Amplify Storage uses cognito auth, and cognito as access to S3 and uses a service role to gain access to pass the file to S3.

Amplify Storage would be a tiny bit slower in this case, because of the intermediate auth, but mostly the same.

Comment: Clearification Amplify Storage does not HAVE to use cognito auth, but it does in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the response @bbebin So in short, I should be using S3.ManageUpload instead of Storage.put ?

Comment: yes, unless you are using cognito